# Fetch data from database and create multi dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to make multidimensional array by fetching data from the database. The second array which is podcast added by a specific user is created however, it is not giving the output of another user which is active in the database.
Here is my code:

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/config/init.php'; 

require CLASS_PATH.'user.php';
require CLASS_PATH.'podcast.php';
$user = new User();
$podcast = new Podcast();

$userList = $user->getAllUserName();

foreach ($userList as $users) {

    $fullname = $users->first_name. ' '. $users->last_name; 
    $data = array(
        'name'  => $fullname

    );

    $podcastList = $podcast->getUserPodcast($fullname);
    $data['podcast'] = $podcastList;
}
```

Comment: What's the actual problem here? is podcast giving results of another user? or you can make multi array?

Comment: What do you mean by, and what makes you think ___it is giving the output of another user___ Show us the output, and describe what is wrong with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build a list of the data up.  Creating the data as 1 item will stop the `podcast` data being separated from the `fullname`...

```
$userList = $user->getAllUserName();
$data = [];
foreach ($userList as $users) {
    $fullname = $users->first_name. ' '. $users->last_name; 
    $data[] = array(
        'name'  => $fullname,
        'podcast' => $podcast->getUserPodcast($fullname)
    );
}
```

To only users with podcasts...

```
$userList = $user->getAllUserName();
$data = [];
foreach ($userList as $users) {
    $fullname = $users->first_name. ' '. $users->last_name; 
    $podcast = $podcast->getUserPodcast($fullname);
    if ( !empty($podcast) )  {
        $data[] = array(
            'name'  => $fullname,
            'podcast' => $podcast
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is working properly but, can we do something if the field of the podcast is empty of a user? Can we remove that the user from array?

Comment: I've updated the code with a new version.  The idea is to check the podcast before adding the user.  I'm assuming it will be empty, you may need to tweak the test according to what this value is when there isn't a podcast.